# PnP PeoplePicker not working on full names

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, people-picker, pnp

Below is the PnP Peoplepicker control code that I'm using. The issue that I'm having here is with space-character within the name. Say I have valid user "Rachel Green". If I type-in "Rachel" I get 10 different Rachel's. So continue to type "Rachel " or "Rachel G" or "Rachel Green", I get no results found. Is there anyway to deal with space-char or able to search based on full name. (If I go by last name i.e Green, since I have only one colleague with Green I'm able to pick correct name).

```
                        <PeoplePicker
                         peoplePickerCntrlclassName=""
                         context={this.props.context}
                         titleText=""
                         personSelectionLimit={1}
                         groupName={""}
                         showtooltip={false}
                         suggestionsLimit = {10}
                         disabled={false}
                         selectedItems={this._getSelectedProfile}
                         principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
                         defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.defaultUser}
                         resolveDelay={1000}
                         errorMessage={this.state.required}
                       />
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Did sample test while not reproduced.

[image]

My dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.8.2",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.8.2",
    "@pnp/common": "^1.3.10",
    "@pnp/logging": "^1.3.10",
    "@pnp/odata": "^1.3.10",
    "@pnp/pnpjs": "^1.3.2",
    "@pnp/sp": "^1.3.10",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "^1.14.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "16.7.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "6.143.0",
    "react": "16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "16.7.0"
  }
```

Comment: thanks, @Lee_MSFT. I do have the same pkg versions now, but no luck. Interestingly what I observed is, I'm able to refine results by UPN(and not full name) i.e in my example, I'm able to type "rachel.gre" and find Rachel Green. Do we have any prop that needs to point at display name rather than UPN?